# How do I set the vertical line distance in Time Cartesian charts in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I want to have the following vertical lines to be in distances of 15 minutes fixed, is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

This is my current code:

```
scales: {
    x: {
        type: 'time',
        time: {
            unit: 'minute',
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 15
            },
            displayFormats: {
                minute: 'HH:mm',
                hour: 'HH:mm',
            }
        },
        min: '{{ tour.chart_min }}',
        max: '{{ tour.chart_max }}',
    },
    y: { beginAtZero: false }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scale config doesn't seem consistent.
You added "ticks" inside the "time" node.

Try thee following:

```
scales: {
    x: {
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 15
        },
        time: {
            unit: 'minute',
            displayFormats: {
                minute: 'HH:mm',
                hour: 'HH:mm',
            }
        },
        min: '{{ tour.chart_min }}',
        max: '{{ tour.chart_max }}',
    },
    y: { beginAtZero: false }
},
```